# how to create a new class in a CodeFixProvider

Tags: c#, roslyn, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio Preview and I would like create a simple Diagnostic with Code Fix:
I would like to check every function and if more than n parameters are present, replace them with a class that I create and contains those parameters as members.
Where I can find more infos on how to do this?

The first part is very easy, but I don't have any idea how to do this in the code fixer

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2):

Override [`GetChangedDocumentAsync`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/CodeActions/CodeAction.cs,102) in your `CodeAction` to return `document.WithSyntaxRoot(...)`, passing a new syntax tree with your new class inserted.

To create the syntax tree, use `document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().InsertNodesAfter(...)`, inserting a `ClassDeclarationSyntax` at some point in the document.